# How can I get the value of the spinner that I've created in the layout programmatically and inserted it multiple times?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/principaltxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Principal"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/principal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:entries="@array/Principal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Item"
                        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/item"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:alpha="0.8"
                        android:entries="@array/Product" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Quantity"
                        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/qty"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:alpha="0.8"
                        android:entries="@array/Quantity" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Item Code"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/itemCode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Remarks per order"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rmrksPO"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And when I clicked my button I insert a layout in my parent layout. This is my child layout that I created separately.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Principal"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/principal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:entries="@array/Principal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Item"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:entries="@array/Product" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Quantity"
                android:textColor="@color/Black" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/qty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:entries="@array/Quantity" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Item Code"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Remarks per order"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rmrksPO"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The thing is I don't know how can I get any value in the child layout that I inserted. Take note that I will insert this layout multiple times.

```
TextView addNew, principal;
LinearLayout linearlayout;
Spinner spnPrincipal;
View inflatedLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_form);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    spnPrincipal = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.principal);
    linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    principal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.principaltxt);
    addNew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addNew);
    addNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(OrderForm.this);
            inflatedLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_item, null, false);
            linearlayout.addView(inflatedLayout);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: after adding a view to hierarchy, you can `findViewById()` it

Comment: But I will insert that child layout multiple times. Can you teach me?

Comment: ok, that way FindViewById won't work. But what you can do is to save added layouts to some list apon adding each, and calling findViewById on that added layout.

Comment: Are you suggesting that when I add a layout i will save the value of findViewById in ArrayList?

Comment: almost that. But your approach should work too.

Comment: Okay sir. I'll try that hope it works. Can you help me if i can't resolve it?